How can I derive $V$ from the following equation?
$$
[(U-V)^{-1}X^{T}Y]^{T}\;[(U-V)^{-1}X^{T}Y] = I.
$$
Here $U$ and $V$ are symmetric $d \times d$ matrices; $X$ is an $n \times d$ data matrix ($n$ is the number of samples and $d$ is the number of data dimensions); $Y$ is an $n \times c$ label matrix ($c$ is the number of classes).

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.
